# Suggestion for Database table design

Tags: database, database-design

I have 2 tables I plan on creating, Employee and Student. Employee and Student tables have some common fields and also some different ones. Is it a good idea to put those same fields in a common table like Person and then relate them?

For example, both Employee and Student have FirstName and LastName fields.

Comment: Relational thinking is not object oriented thinking.

Answer (score 0):

### PersonType

personTypeID     (1 ,2 )

personTypeName (student,employee )

### Person

PersonID

PersonType (foreignKey From PersonType)

PersonName

PersonSurname

### Employee

EmployeeID (ForeignKey from Person table and also primaryKey of this table, since all employees are person or you can make a unqiue empID for this table and make a column like fkPersonID which must be unique fot this table as well)

EmployeeDepID (fk from departmens)

Budget

and so on

### Students

Exactly same approach as Employee table.

Since you didn't mentioan about for a student which might be an employee or vice versa i didn't consider this situation. Assuming that a student might be an employee as well just create a column in students table which is fkEmpID from employee table. But in this situation if you create fkPersonID in both employee and student table you have to guarantee these two columns matches. To provide in your student table get both (fkPersonID, fkEmpID) and match them (fkPersonID,fkEmpID) this is called multi-column foreign keys.

Comment: Thanks for answering. However, I was looking for an explanation or reason on why doing the design structure I asked is good or bad. I want to know why I should/shouldn't do this.

Comment: yes you should, in the future if you just need name and surname attributes of both stu and emp, you can only extract the data from person table otherwise you will have to union two queries. What you are asking is one of normalization rules.